# Appending String

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, nsstring

i am having this code to show some text for particular chapter,i am using core text.but my need is,when the text of the first chapter ends it wants to show the next chapter text in newline.my code for showing text is

```
NSMutableString *combined = [NSMutableString string];

    for(NSUInteger idx = 0; idx < [delegatee.allSelectedVerseEnglish count]; idx++) {
        [combined appendFormat:@"  %d %@", 
         idx + 1, 
         [delegatee.allSelectedVerseEnglish objectAtIndex:idx]];

    }

    self.multiPageView.text =combined;
```

multipageview is the view that i render text through core text.so my need is i have first chapter text in "combined".so i want to append the combined with next chapter,the code for showing next chapter is

```
delegatee.selectedChapter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[delegatee.selectedChapter intValue] + 1];
    [delegatee reloadVerses];
    [self resetReadViewToVerse:1];
```

combined contains text like these...1 haii this is my first sentence 2 this is my second sentence 3 this is my third sentence ,,etch etc..so if the third sentence is the last text ,then in a /n newline i need next chapter text..
i put this code in button to navigate to next chapter,but i need it automatically after ending each chapter .

is it possible?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do i understand it correctly that `allSelectedVerseEnglish` returns all the verses for the selected chapter and there's no method to get the verses by a chapter number ?

Comment: @A-Live yes it returns all the verse for the selected chapter,there is no method to get the verse by chapter number

Comment: @A-Live but i can select the book,chapter and verse

Comment: @A-Live is there any way to append this?thnks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first place you might want to prepare a method to receive the verses by a chapter number (to get the verses of the next chapter as you want to display it).

Between your `for` loop and `self.multiPageView.text =combined;` you should calculate the number of lines occupied in the last "page", this allows you to calculate the number of lines to be filled from the next chapter based on the maximum "page" number of lines.

Now when you have both the next chapter verses and the number of lines to be added, you can pretty easily append the next chapter lines to fill the "page" using `while` loop. There're two important conditions to take into consideration:

- there might be no next chapter - you skip the next chapter text appending, disable the next chapter button, etc.
- there's no empty lines on the last "page" to be filled but there's a next chapter - you skip the next chapter text appending, but the next chapter button is enabled

The resulting code looks like this:

```
NSMutableString *combined = @"";
NSArray * selectedChapterVersesArray = [delegatee.allVersesForLanguage:kEngLang atChapter:delegatee.selectedChapter];

if (selectedChapterVersesArray != nil && [selectedChapterVersesArray count] > 0)

// prepare the selected chapter text
for(NSUInteger idx = 0; idx < [selectedChapterVersesArray count]; idx++) {
    [combined appendFormat:@"  %d %@ \n", 
     idx + 1, 
     [selectedChapterVersesArray objectAtIndex:idx]];

}

// calculate the lines found to be added from the next chapter - to be implemented !
NSUInteger linesToAddFromNextChapter = [self emptyLinesForMultipageView:self.multipageview withText:combined];

if (delegatee.numberOfChapters > delegatee.selectedChapter)
{
// there's a next chapter
NSArray * nextChapterVersesArray = [delegatee.allVersesForLanguage:kEngLang atChapter:delegatee.selectedChapter+1];

// append the next chapter text
NSUInteger linesAdded = 0;
BOOL nextChapterHasLinesToAdd = [nextChapterVersesArray count] > 0;

while (linesAdded < linesToAddFromNextChapter && nextChapterHasLinesToAdd) {
  // append one line, inc linesAdded, recalculate nextChapterHasLinesToAdd
}
}
}

self.multiPageView.text =combined;
delegatee.selectedChapter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[delegatee.selectedChapter intValue] + 1];
[delegatee reloadVerses];
[self resetReadViewToVerse:1];
```

Note, you've lost the line break character `\n` in the format literal, the code is just a draft, and there're methods to be implemented.

Comment: i don't know how to cacuate the lines per chapter,i am struck there.but your code is really correct.but i don't think i can figure it out.its my mistake.

Comment: I don't know what's your `multiPageView` implementation, if that's a `UIScrollView` subclass(like the `UITextView` is), then instead of adding the new lines you can add the complete verses from the next chapter at the while loop. The condition to stop will be a)all verses added b) `multiPageView.contentSize.height > kMultiPageViewHeight`, then you can change the "page" `contentInset` to truncate the excess lines for b) or `contentSize` with the predefined width and height for a). Hope it helps.

Comment: yeaa,multipage view is coming from akosomo coretextwarper,am using that,its a subclass of scrolview.if you r free now,can you come to Skype?i will share my screen.i think its really simple for you like expert iOS coders.if today is not possible,can you com on taro this time?anyway my Skype id is nips_fingent